# Mysql query with a join back to the same table and a count

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table:

```
InvoiceItem
----------------
id     
type      <- 'ITEM' 'FEE' 'OTHER'
parentid  <- InvoiceItem id of the parent invoice item
<some other columns>
```

How can I join this table to itself, get all the InvoiceItem columns where id = given id plus one that gives me a true|false 1|0 if the table has any items in it that have a given InvoiceItem id as the parentid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Using a correlated subquery:

   ```
   SELECT a.*,
          EXISTS(SELECT * FROM InvoiceItem b WHERE b.parentid = a.id)
            AS has_children
   FROM   InvoiceItem a
   WHERE  a.id = ?
   ```
2. Using an outer join:

   ```
   SELECT a.*, COUNT(b.id) > 0 AS has_children
   FROM   InvoiceItem a LEFT JOIN InvoiceItem b ON b.parentid = a.id
   WHERE  a.id = ?
   ```

Comment: is either one of these going to perform better than the other?

Comment: @kasdega: Try benchmarking them?  If you're filtering the resultset on `a.id` as shown above, I wouldn't expect any material difference between the two; if you retrieved such results for multiple records, I would generally expect the second (outer join) approach to yield better performance.